# SQL How to insert data from two different table into one table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently working to get the data from TWO different tables into another one. However, I want to insert data from the NAMES table and DEAD table into my new NAME table. Below is my codes and table. Any help will be a great and thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
NAME_ID varchar(9),
NAME varchar(35),
BIRTHYEAR varchar(4) );
```

The DEAD table:

```
CREATE TABLE DEAD( 
DEATH_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DEATHYEAR INTEGER);
```

My new Name that that I want to insert the data to:

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
NAME_ID VARCHAR(60),
NAME  VARCHAR (40),
BIRTHYEAR int,
DEATH_ID int );
```

Below is my insert code and every time I run it, I get that error;

```
Insert into NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
Select NAME_ID ,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, (select DISTINCT DEATH_ID FROM DEAD)
from NAMES;
```

The error:

```
Error starting at line : 77 in command -
Insert into NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
Select NAME_ID ,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, (select DISTINCT DEATH_ID FROM DEAD)
from NAMES
Error report -
SQLORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Comment: How can we tell which name relates to which death?

Comment: This looks like exactly the same question you asked yesterday ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958597/sql-how-to-insert-from-two-different-table-into-one-table

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query with `CROSS JOIN` containing `DISTINCT` operator :

```
INSERT INTO NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
SELECT DISTINCT N.NAME_ID , N.NAME, N.BIRTHYEAR, D.DEATH_ID
  FROM NAMES N
 CROSS JOIN DEAD D;
```

**Update :** If you need not to insert any row provided `DEATH_ID` is null, and can join two tables by `DEATH_ID` and `NAME_ID`, then use a such an `OUTER JOIN` :

```
INSERT INTO NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
SELECT DISTINCT N.NAME_ID , N.NAME, N.BIRTHYEAR, D.DEATH_ID
  FROM NAMES N
  LEFT JOIN DEAD D
    ON D.DEATH_ID = N.NAME_ID
 WHERE D.DEATH_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out but it is still stored duplicated data, thank you again

Comment: you're welcome. Can you share some sample data? @Omar

Comment: For example the DEAD table has 151 rows and the name_id, names and the BIRTHDAY are  39000 rows. The plan to insert all of them into the new Name table and for the names who doesn't have death_id will have null. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean null names or no rows will be generated @Omar ?

Comment: I think you don't need WHERE D.DEATH_ID IS NOT NULL. I understand he only want Null if there is no match found on the join. You already did that with the left join.

Comment: well, he says *for the names who doesn't have death_id will have null* @davidev, and assumed he doesn't want to generate any rows for null death_id values.

Comment: You are right but the issue here is when I run the above insert code it stored the same name for 151 times. Is there away that can make it store the data only one time. Thank for your help

Comment: golden rule is adding some sample data and desired output @Omar :)

Comment: This is working fine for me.. @Omar you then might have duplicated values in your table. Thats difficult to recreate

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is wrong, you need to return one row. At the moment you are making two separate selections. Just make one selection with a join.

```
INSERT INTO NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
SELECT n.NAME_ID, n.NAME, n. BIRTHYEAR, d.DEATH_ID 
FROM NAMES n 
LEFT JOIN DEAD d ON n.NAME_ID = d.DEATH_ID
```

You might want to make a `WHERE` clause.. not sure how you want to add the `DEATH_ID`

Comment: Hi, first thank you for helping me but that code didn't work, I an getting this error: Error starting at line : 77 in command -
INSERT INTO NAME(NAME_ID,NAME, BIRTHYEAR, DEATH_ID )
SELECT n.NAME_ID, n.NAME, n.BIRTHDAY, d.DEATH_ID FROM NAMES n, DEAD d
Error at Command Line : 78 Column : 27
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "N"."BIRTHDAY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Omar Thanks.. I updated the code. There was a typo mistake.

Comment: it did work but how do i get rid of the duplicated data and thanks

Comment: @Omar Good.. thats what I meant with the WHERE condition. What DEATH_ID should be added to the row?

Comment: The problem here is that the name_id, names and the BIRTHDAY are repeated. For example it stored the same name more than 5 times and same with the other. Many thanks.

Comment: @Omar Yes, this is intended because it will merge all of the content of DEAD table onto the rows. Which value of the DEAD table do you want to be merged?

Comment: For example the DEAD table has 151 rows and the name_id, names and the BIRTHDAY are  39000 rows. The plan to insert all of them into the new Name table and for the names who doesn't have death_id will have null. Thank you.

Comment: I understand.. but how do you do the mapping. Is the DEATH_ID the NAME_ID??

Comment: Yes because the Name_id is the FK

Comment: @Omar Okay now understand :) Will update the code above

Comment: It did work but it still the same issue the duplicated data. What if I use Union, will that work and Thank you